# How to get value out of mono

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webclient

I'm trying to extract a `String` out out `Mono`.

Mono method:

```
public Mono<String> getVal() {
    return webClient.get()
        .uri("/service") 
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class);
}
```

Calling `getVal()`:

```
String val = getVal().block();
```

I tried using `block()` but it returns the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, 
which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-3
```

I suppose I would have to use a non-blocking method like `subscribe()` which I'm not to sure how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using reactive programming, try to avoid blocking calls and use already existing features.

```java
public Mono<String> getVal() {
    return webClient.get()
        .uri("/service") 
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .map(str ->  {
          // You have your string unwrapped here
          return str;
        });
}
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for answering. The tricky part is getting the value out of the lambda expression and storing it in a local variable. Is it possible for this case?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But should you do that? When you mix things (reactive and blocking), things get out of control easily. Try to have callback methods that uses this "val" you are trying to retrieve and pass it to them without breaking the method chain.

Answer (score 0):

Ghokun has a better answer. But if anyone wants to use a blocking method:

I modified my `getVal()` method:

```
public String getVal() {
    String response = "";

        try {
            response = webClient.get()
                .uri("/service") 
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .toFuture()
                .get();
            
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            
        }
                
        return response;
}
```